# How to tunnel the serial port from a remote machine?

Tags: forwarding, serial, tunnel, tty, socat

I'm trying to access a remote serial console (a tty port on a remote machine) as if it's on a local machine. This is necessary for a serial-port only application to work on my machine. The remote tty is not directly accessible. It is behind an OpenGear and I can connect to the actual tty only with telnet. If necessary I could drop the OpenGear just to confirm that things work without it in the middle.

I want to tell my application to use a local device like /tmp/my_virtual_tty and connect to the OpenGear telnet port transparently.

What works:

```
$ telnet remote_telnet remote_port

$ socat TCP:remote_telnet:remote_port TCP-LISTEN:10023
$ telnet localhost 10023
```

What doesn't work (nothing seems to get exchanged) but I wish it would:

```
$ socat tcp-connect:remote_telnet:remote_port PTY,link=$HOME/dev/vmodem0
$ screen $HOME/dev/vmodem0
```

The same thing with [remserial](http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/):

```
$ remserial -d -r remote_telnet -p remote_port -l $HOME/dev/vmodem0 /dev/ptmx
$ screen $HOME/dev/vmodem0 .... # doesn't work either
```

This doesn't work either but since I did not specify any tty speed anywhere it might make sense:

```
$ screen $HOME/dev/vmodem0 115200
```

I tried raw/rawer options with socat and played with raw options of OpenGear without success.
My questions are: what am I not seeing and what is the actual solution for remote serial port forwarding/tunneling?

Comment: I think there's selinux issue. `socat` and `screen` are needed root privileges. Don't use home directory for devices. Create devices in `/dev` directory and you will not have any problems with selinux.

Comment: Selinux is disabled since I need all the freedom I can get on my work machine. The home file is just a symlink to /dev/pts/<x> and it's not at the root of the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

This will work seamlessly but only with a raw server (on the Opengear) and not with a telnet one:

```
$ socat -d TCP:server:port PTY,link=$HOME/dev/vmodem0,rawer,b115200,sane
$ screen ~/dev/vmodem0
```

That's it. Remserial will work exactly the same way so there is no need for a proprietary driver unless you are on Windows and probably not even then.

In fact, OpenGear provides "portshare" drivers for both Windows and Linux but they are very outdated and buggy: http://ftp.opengear.com/download/portshare/

!! A secondary problem in my case was that even though raw server was active, the firewall was blocking the port (NB: Within Opengear, setting access ports rights is done from a different webpage than the firewall :)

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer for your question to use a remserial or such software, but for enterprise need like that I use some virtual port product that are created for such need. It's in big a RJ45 to serial adapter. That way you can easily have any VM or any gear that access that serial port/tty.

I know one product that do it, [Perle iOLAN](https://www.perle.com/products/iolan-ds-terminal-server.shtml#overview), but I guess it exist a lot more of such products.

In my case it was a VM that used to talk to a serial modem over a ESX cluster, as that way the VM can see it anywhere it's run on.

Comment: The Opengear device does serial over ethernet so this part is covered. I'm interested in converting back to serial on my local machine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @crististm Ah ok, didnt know that part. they don't provide driver to do it then ? as the device I paste, there is a linux driver available, that do the connection over a virtual driver/device

Comment: I can ask. However being just a Linux box I imagine there are free/open source solutions to convert telnet back to serial just like ser2net does the oposite. At least both socat and remserial suggest this through their docs

Comment: @crististm can you gave the part number of your device ? its easy to check

Comment: Yes, but that would not change much unless the solution is only to use opengear with their telnet to serial driver. But what could I do if I used ser2net instead?

Comment: @crististm yeah, but for the ser2net did you removed the opengear to do the test ?